# How to read Email and write to a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

My scenario,i need to filter email by certain department and write those email to a sharepoint list.Any idea how that can be accomplished and i need to deploy the solution so that the whole company can use it.

Comment: Where are the email stored? Is it via site mailbox?

Comment: @VainkteshKumar the emails are on outlook app.

Comment: Are you trying to read mails of certain mailbox or all users? If certain mailbox for which you know the credentials then it is very easy. If not then please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 1):

check out connectors, refer to the link:
https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/seven-connectors-and-html/

Answer (score 1):

Use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.dll to read the email from Outlook context and extract the data. Then use CSOM(C#) to add email to a SharePoint document library. Check the articles below:

[Here's how to read emails from Outlook using C#](https://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2017/04/read-emails-from-outlook.html#dXrWdAJyWMB2RUy2.97)

[Uploading a file into a library via CSOM, even if the library does not exist](https://piasys.com/blog/uploading-a-file-into-a-library-via-csom-even-if-the-library-does-not-exist/)

Comment: can you read others mailbox??